# Sort and append content based on value difference of specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm attempting to create a function that sorts elements based on their numerical separation from the data-attribute value of a designated "leader."

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- If the participant data-title value is less than or equal to 4 from the data-title of the "leader" then they are appended to playoffs
- If the data-title value is greater than 4 from the data-title of the "leader" than they are appended to out.

I'm hoping to keep the leader in place and only sort/append the elements that are equal to or larger than the leader data-title into their respective categories. How can I adjust the code below to facilitate something like this?

```js
var participant = $('.participant')
var leader = $('#leader')

$(participant).sort(function (a, b) {

  var contentA = parseInt( $('.participant').data('title'));
  var contentB = parseInt( $(leader).data('title'));
  
  if (contentA - contentB <= 4) {
   $(participant).appendTo('#in-race');
  }
  else {
   $(participant).appendTo('#out');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.section-hold {
  margin: 2em 0;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.participant{
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.name{
  float: left;
}
.score{
  float: right;
}
.section-title{
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #FFF;
}
#participant-hold{
  outline: solid 1px grey;
}
#in-race{
  outline: solid 1px yellow;
}
#out{
  outline: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-hold" id="participant-hold">
  <h3 class="section-title">PARTICIPANTS</h3>
  
  <div class="participant">
    <div class="name">LEADER</div>
    <div class="score" id="leader" data-title="18"><em>18</em></div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="participant">
    <div class="name">TEST 1</div>
    <div class="score" data-title="21.5"><em>21.5</em></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="participant">
    <div class="name">TEST 2</div>
    <div class="score" data-title="28"><em>28</em></div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="section-hold" id="in-race">
  <h3 class="section-title">PLAYOFFS</h3>
  
</div>


<div class="section-hold" id="out">
  <h3 class="section-title">OUT</h3>
  
</div>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the leader in place and only sort the other participants you can do this:

```js
var participant = $('.participant:not(:has(#leader))');
var leader = $('#leader')

participant.each(function() {
   var contentA = parseInt($(this).find(".score").data("title"));
   var contentB = parseInt(leader.data("title"));
   if (contentA - contentB <= 4) {
      $(this).appendTo('#in-race');
   } else {
      $(this).appendTo('#out');
   }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.section-hold {
  margin: 2em 0;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.participant{
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.name{
  float: left;
}
.score{
  float: right;
}
.section-title{
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #FFF;
}
#participant-hold{
  outline: solid 1px grey;
}
#in-race{
  outline: solid 1px yellow;
}
#out{
  outline: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-hold" id="participant-hold">
  <h3 class="section-title">PARTICIPANTS</h3>

  <div class="participant">
    <div class="name">LEADER</div>
    <div class="score" id="leader" data-title="18"><em>18</em></div>
  </div>

  <div class="participant">
    <div class="name">TEST 1</div>
    <div class="score" data-title="21.5"><em>21.5</em></div>
  </div>

  <div class="participant">
    <div class="name">TEST 2</div>
    <div class="score" data-title="28"><em>28</em></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="section-hold" id="in-race">
  <h3 class="section-title">PLAYOFFS</h3>

</div>


<div class="section-hold" id="out">
  <h3 class="section-title">OUT</h3>

</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense. Why would the "TEST 1" participant be in the "out" section if it's data-title value is less than four from the leader value?

Comment: @istark Both participants have been in the "out" section because the value of the data-title was not retrieved correctly. I adjusted this in my updated answer. Question is if the "TEST 2" participant should be in the playoffs as it is now as the data-title value is 10 from the leader value and you wrote "If the data-title value is greater than 4 from the data-title of the "leader" than they are appended to out".

Comment: "TEST 2" should be in the "out" section since it's data-title is more than 4 from the leader.

Comment: @istark I've adjusted my answer. It's working now using an each() loop instead of a sort() function.